# Get secret value from Azure key vault in YAML script

Tags: bash, azure, azure-devops, yaml, devops

I tried to use the variable directly which was downloaded through AzureKeyVault task. But while trying to fetch it, I am using an intermediary common variable which points to variable in keyvalult like this - $($(DBUserName)). Variable DBUserName has value to key vault secret name i.e.

```
variables:
  DBUserName: sqlServerAdminUsername
```

But this does not return value from key vault but returns - $(sqlServerAdminUsername) which is not the expected result. Can you help on this?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

We could add the task bash and enter the script `printenv` to check all variable. We need to get the variable via `$(DBUserName)` or `$($env:DBUSERNAME)` instead of `$($(DBUserName))`. If the DBUserName value is `xxx`, it will also return `$(xxx)`. Check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#secret-variables) and this [blog](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/azurekeyvault/) for more details.

Comment: Hi @Panicker, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?